# Looping through nested arrays and return exclusive results

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, redux

I have some issues (basic JS nesting and filtering) retrieving 'exclusive' filtered data from a nested array object. The code is for a React project. I may introduce lodash if required.

I have an array with 1 or more (and maybe 0 as well, in which case the default values are returned) strings in an array:

```
let arrayA = ["string-1", "string-2"]; //assume them to be skill slugs
```

I declare a new array to hold data that is pushed into it later on:

```
let newArr1 = [];
```

My nested main Array:

```
      /*Top level skillset category, within each of which a skills array resides (propC).
        Within each skill there is an array of projects associated with that particular skill (propC3). 
        Projects can have multiple skills so projects in one skill may perhaps reside in other skills as well.*/
     let arrayB =[ //the top level skillset category
        {
        "propA": "valueA1",
        "propB": "valueB1",
        "propC":[ //the skills array
            {
            "propC1": "valueC11",
            "matchthis": "string-1", //the unique skill slug
            "proppC2": "valueC12",

            "propC3": [ //projects
                {
                propC31: "valueC131",
                },
                {
                propC32: "valueC132",
                }

                ]

            },

            {
                "propC1": "valueC12",
                "matchthis": "string-2",
                "proppC2": "valueC12",

                "propC3": [
                    {
                    propC31: "valueC131",
                    },
                    {
                    propC32: "valueC232",
                    }

                    ]

                }

        ],
        "propD": "valueD1"      
        },
        {
        "propA": "valueA2",
        "propB": "valueB2",
        "propC":[
            {
            "propC1": "valueC21",
            "matchthis": "string-2",
            "proppC2": "valueC22",
            "proppC3": [
                {
                propC31: "valueC231",
                },
                {
                propC32: "valueC132",
                }

                ]

            }
        ],
        "propD": "valueD1"      
        },


    ]
```

I need to filter my `arrayB` nested array so that only a subset of data is returned which is based on the strings in the `arrayA` array. I use the `newArray1` array to hold this data. I can have duplicate data(when i push into the `newArray` array) so i remove them as well, either via `vanilla JS` or `lodash`.

My attempt:

```
arrayA.map((a,i)=>{
   return arrayB.filter((b,j)=>{
     return b.propC.filter((c,k)=>{
        return a===c.matchthis
       }).map((o,i)=>{
        o.propC3.map((o,i)=>{
         newArr1.push(o)
        })

      })                 
     })
   })
```

When i push the data there is a possibility of duplicates, so i remove them next:

```
 // newArr1 =  newArr1.filter((s1, pos, arr) => arr.findIndex((s2)=>s2.project_id === s1.project_id) === pos); //JS
 newArr1 = _.uniqBy(newArr1, 'project_id'); //lodash
```

I cant seem to get an `exclusion` going. By exclusive i mean data that resides in `newArray1` (the projects) should only have projects that have all the the skills passed in `arrayA` - if one fails there is no result. If i had passed `["html5", "css", "react"]` then only projects that contain these skills should be returned.

I can get 'inclusive' results going with my current approach.

The scenario is thus: user selects one or more skills (from a collection of skills) and i display projects that include all these skills (exclusive approach). Since the skills reside in categories, skills can sometimes reside in more than one category.  I may in have a switch which allows the user to select between an inclusive and exclusive filtering, but definitely not now.

Here is the more or less actual array object, contracted for brevity:

```
       [{
        skillltype_id:”0”,
        skills: [
       {
        skill_id: ”0”,
        skill_name: "HTML5”,    
        skill_slug:"html5”,
        ….
        projects: [
             {
                     project_id :”0”,
                     project_name: “Lorem Ipsum 1”,         
                     project_slug: “a-slug”
                     …
             },

             {
                     project_id :”2”,
                     project_name: “Lorem Ipsum 2”,         
                     project_slug: “b-slug”
                     …
             },
             ….
         ]

     },
     {
     skill_id: ”2”,
     skill_name: “javascript”,
     skill_slug:”javascript”,
    ….
     projects: [
             {
                     project_id :”100”,
                     project_name: “Lorem Ipsum 1”,                      
                     project_slug: “a-slug”
                     …

             },
             {
                     project_id :”2”,
                     project_name: “Lorem Ipsum 2”,                      
                     project_slug: “b-slug”
                     …
             },
             ….
         ]
     }

     ],
     skilltype_description:"Lorem Ipsum”,
     skilltype_name:”Lorem Ipsum”,
     skilltype_shortdescription:"Lorem Ipsum”,
     },

     ……..
     ……

     ]
```

**UPDATE: Adding a wanted result:**

Based on the example arrays shown at the top of this question, passing `["html5","css"]` as `arrayA`

should return an array with a list of projects that is contained inside `arrayB` > `propC` > `propC3` as `newArray1`(or any name) where each element in `arrayA` is matched by the `matchthis` property in `propC`.

If only one string matches (for example `html5`) then it cannot be considered and will return an empty array. All passed strings have to match for it to be considered exclusive.

For additional clarity: based on the arrayB example with near actual data(towards the end of the question), passing `["html5","css"]` as an array

should return an array of projects that is contained in `skills` > `projects` where each element(string) is matched with the `skill_slug` property in the `skills` array.

- `arrayA` is the array with the values im going to use to search
- `arrayB` is the skillsets category array which consists of a skills array named `propC`.
- Each skill inside `propC` consists of a projects array named `propC3` and also has a `matchthis` property that can be used to match the string from `arrayA`.

**Update 2: Adding more information for clarity**

The project uses `redux` and `thunks` so definitely non-mutative as a principle. I did not mention this as i thought that this particular issue was more of a basic JS basics sort of problem.

This particular section of code is in an `action creator` prior to dispatching.

I do have to mention that i do a `slice()` from the `getState()` function parameter (of the redux store-returned object) a few lines earlier on to get `arrayB` so essentially the code that i have added here is mutatable because i am working on a unique copy. The final array(`newArray1`) will be passed as the payload for the state.

So it really doesn't matter if a new array is created(in fact `newArray1` is a newly created array just to hold the data from the filtering operations) or if the existing(the code added here) array is mutated.

I also think that creating a new array just to hold the filtered data may not be required and can perhaps be solved via multiple chained `map` and `filter` and similar methods. But as of now want to keep it simple during early development.

This is my first `react-redux` project(beyond study projects) so i do try to be careful about mutating the state and sometimes go overboard with creating copies.

flow:

- user selects a skill, i dispatch an action and add the skill slug to a `selectedskill` array that exists in the store
- the above is a `Promise`, so in a `then` i dispatch an action for displaying relevant projects based on the selected skill(s)
- this action is where this issue comes in. I use the `getState()` and `slice()` to get a copy of the `skillsets` object from the store(`arrayB`) which has all the skillsets each of which with skills and each skill also consisting of matching projects. I also have the `selectedskills` array available(`arrayA`). Now i need to match them and filter out exclusive projects that is nested (`arrayB` > `propC` > `propC3`)
- assuming i get the data i want (with a new array or by just multiple chaining of map and filter) i return this array as the payload to be dispatched to the reducer so that my UI will now show projects that are pertinent to all of the selected skills.
- (a side note: I have an array of all the projects available. Very early,  as the page opens, I extract out all these projects from all the `skillsets` and `skills` and after de-duplication kept them as a large and unique `allprojects` array I can use if required. I am not using it as i think, considering that the data is finite so my `skillsets` array wont be too large and i can continue using it as the primary source of data and use it whenever required)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: I wonder why the downvote.  A valid reason helps to make sure that future questions don't have the same issues. The question is quite elaborate. Perhaps too long maybe. The (valid) suggested edit of the "wanted result" section has also been added.

Comment: you added a description, which is great, but not the object itself, which would help to answer the question.

Comment: ok. I thought it was an anonymous action with no comment. I hope the question is clearer now with the edit.

Comment: no it is not. for example, do you need a new array? does it matter if the original data gets mutated?

Comment: So am I mis-interpreting your problem?

Comment: @Nick: No, not at all. I added the second update while the answer was being posted so i didn't notice it. I just saw the answer. From first look(without adding it to the IDE) it looks to be the solution. I will update the answer with comments after actual integration. Its a rather long question and with all the updates it got even longer.

Comment: Good to hear. It was indeed long reading, but it made for an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one way of doing it. First we create a `Projects` object:

```
let Projects = {};
```

Now we fill that with all the skills requirements of the projects in arrayB:

```
arrayB.map((b) => { 
  b.propC.map((c) => { 
    // note had to use old-style function here to get this to be correctly assigned in Firefox
    c.propC3.map(function (c3) {
      // get the name of the project
      let name = c3[Object.keys(c3)[0]];
      if (Projects.hasOwnProperty(name))
        Projects[name].push(this.toString());
      else
        Projects[name] = [this.toString()];
    }, c.matchthis); 
  }); 
});
```

In this example `console.log(Projects)` gives:

```
{…}
valueC131: Array [ "string-1", "string-2" ]
valueC132: Array [ "string-1", "string-2" ]
valueC231: Array [ "string-2" ]
valueC232: Array [ "string-2" ]
__proto__: Object { … }
```

Now we can simply compare the elements of `Projects` against the skills in `arrayA`. Any projects that require **all** the skills in `arrayA` will be pushed into `newArr`:

```
let newArr = [];
for (p in Projects) {
  if (Projects.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    if (arrayA.reduce((t, s) => { return t && (Projects[p].indexOf(s) >= 0); }, true)) newArr.push(p);
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Output:

```
Array [ "valueC131", "valueC132" ]
```

We can also check for Projects that require **any** of the skills in `arrayA` with a slight code change:

```
newArr = [];
for (p in Projects) {
  if (Projects.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    if (arrayA.reduce((t, s) => { return t || (Projects[p].indexOf(s) >= 0); }, false)) newArr.push(p);
  }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Output:

```
Array [ "valueC131", "valueC132", "valueC232", "valueC231" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will take a look and attempt an integration and will update back here

Comment: It does work though i had to make slight changes when i use the actual data structure that i have. I was getting `this` as `undefined` when doing a push to the array (`this.toString()`). I also am using the project_slug instead of project_name to avoid spaces in the property (though it doesn't matter since it is called via the bracket notation). Thanks for the answer. I may need to make a few modifications to the DB structure so more changes to the code is bound to happen. This is primarily for internal view data (project details and there is a portfolio as well that needs to be integrated.

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work. I also had the problems with this - that's why I changed one of the map functions to an actual function declaration instead of the ES6 style; it just didn't work in Firefox otherwise. It might be a bug as the docs definitely say it should work.